# How to display scrollbar for a list view whose contents keep changing?

Tags: c++, user-interface, scroll

I have a ListView-like control that displays a list of items of various heights.  The contents of the list, and the heights of the items can change – a background thread is populating the list and calculating the layout of each item, possibly even while the user is scrolling the content.
Which brings me to my question:  How do I display a useful vertical scrollbar for this view?  I’ve seen cases (notably web browsers) where the slider “jumps away” from the mouse cursor while the user is dragging it, the result of the underlying content growing in height.  I don’t want that.

So far

1. Instead of the slider representing the viewport height relative to the content height, maybe it could represent a point in a timeline instead?  (The items are sorted by timestamp).  This would at least prevent the scrollbar from changing as item layouts are calculated.
2. Get rid of the scrollbar altogether and use a forward/backward rocker switch like the one used in Picasa (the further the slider is pulled upwards or downwards, the faster the view is scrolled, until the user releases the slider).  If I take this route, are there any controls you can recommend?

I am using Qt, but this applies to UI design in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the fundamental problem with a classic scrollbar is that due to background population, the valid range is changing - and thus, the meaning of a scrollbar position changes.

If you can predict the full range of items, you can still provide a scrollbar and replace yet-unknown items with "loading...".

Otherwise, a rocker (is that an official name?) would be the next best thing to use.

However, since you have a dedicated scale (timeline), it might be better to have separate buttons that jump a dedicated time (e.g. one minute, one hour, one day, ..). For a fancier look, you could create a rocker with "hot" areas that jump for a specific time, whereas the areas inbetween are interpolated (linear or or logarithmic, depending on the scale to cover).

i.e. line this (drawing just the "backward" half):

```
--------------------------
|##|XXXXXXX|##|XXXXXXX|##|
--------------------------
-1h        -1m       -1s
```